# Improving sql code with dynamic column name and values

Tags: sql, t-sql

I spent hours trying to get my head around dynamic sql and could not get anything working. I finally ended up with this code that works but there has to be a better, more sql way of writing it.

```
  DECLARE @ColumnName varchar(20), @Date date,@newValue smallint,@res varchar(20);
  SET @ColumnName = 'dis';
  SET @Date = Convert(varchar(10), GETUTCDATE(),120) ;
  SET @newValue = 150;
  SET @res=0;

If Not Exists (SELECT * FROM dbo.stat WHERE date= Convert(varchar(10), GETUTCDATE(),120) )
BEGIN
INSERT INTO dbo.stat (test) values (0)
END

IF EXISTS (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.stat ) AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM dbo.stat WHERE date= Convert(varchar(10), GETUTCDATE(),120) )
    BEGIN
    UPDATE stat SET  ti  = 
        CASE 
           WHEN @ColumnName ='ti' AND  ID = (  SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.stat ) THEN ti + @newValue 
           ELSE ti
           END,
           cp = CASE 
           WHEN @ColumnName= 'cp' AND  ID = (  SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.stat )THEN cp +@newValue
           ELSE cp
           END,
           oos = CASE 
           WHEN @ColumnName= 'oos' AND  ID = (  SELECT MAX(ID) FROM dbo.stat )THEN oos +@newValue
           ELSE oos
         END;
    END;
```

Basically it receives a column name (@ColumnName) and a value (@newValue). If a row with today`s date does not exit, it creates it and update the value at the column name specified by @ColumnName. If it exists it only updates the value. It will eventually become a stored procedure.

Cheers!

Comment: Curious thing that your `update` has no `where` clause, so it updates all rows. Aside: You can eliminate the `convert` calls. `declare @CurrentDate as Date = GetUTCDate();` will do the right thing, i.e. drop the time. You probably also want to use `@CurrentDate` throughout the code. If it happens to be running around midnight interesting things may happen as the date changes.

Answer (score 0):

The following code ought to do what you need without dynamic SQL:

```
declare @ColumnName as VarChar(20) = 'dis';
declare @CurrentDate as Date = GetUTCDate();
declare @NewValue as SmallInt = 150;

-- Make sure there is a row for today.
if not exists ( select 42 from dbo.stat where Date = @CurrentDate )
  insert into dbo.stat ( test ) values ( 0 );

-- Update the appropriate column in today's row.
update dbo.stat
  set
    ti += case when @ColumnName = 'ti' then @NewValue else 0 end,
    cp += case when @ColumnName = 'cp' then @NewValue else 0 end,
    oos += case when @ColumnName = 'oos' then @NewValue else 0 end
  where Date = @CurrentDate;
```